# Is it possible for me to re-use the trainned model of LSTM RNN in synaptics.js Node?

Tags: node.js, lstm

I tried to predict the time series by using LSTM RNN of synaptic.js - Node neural network Package. I set 1500 of iterations, 70 of memcells and use tons of input data. so it will take about 4 hours to train and test. The trained model was good. after getting the prediction result, I wanted to change input data a bit and re-use this trained model. But I couldn't find the way to save the trained model.
I need your help and advice. thanks

http://caza.la/synaptic/#/

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do! It actually has a built-in function for this. There are two ways to do this.

**If you want to use the network without training it again**

This will create a standalone function of your network, you can use it anywhere with javascript without requiring synaptic.js! [Wiki](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Networks#standalone)

```
var standalone = myNetwork.standalone();
```

**If you want to modify the network later on**

Just convert your network to a JSON. This can be loaded up anytime again with synaptic.js! [Wiki](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Networks#tojsonfromjson)

```
// Export the network to a JSON which you can save as plain text
var exported = myNetwork.toJSON();

// Conver the network back to useable network
var imported = Network.fromJSON(exported);
```